# Partition a lifegame-like program for parallel computing with load balance

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, pthreads, mpi

Consider a lifegame-like computing on a **m*n** matrix, it takes **O(m*n)** to develop each cycle.
I'm going to modify this program to a parallel version using Pthread and MPI. The simplest way is static partition, which means splitting **m** rows to **t** tasks, each task deal with a **m/t * n** matrix. (**t** stands for number of threads or processes) 
However, this solution is not well load balanced. A task may deal with nothing while another has to compute a matrix almost full. 
My first thought to make this computing more load balanced is like this:

> 1. Maintain a m*1 array to store how many elements is in each row.
> 2. After scanning the testcase, allocate i*n matrix for each task.
>      The elements in the matrix should equal to the others tasks.
>      Store the number of elements in each task at the same time.(need a t*1 array here)
> 3. After each cycle, reallocate the matrix bound to each task. It will take O(t*m) to do this.

This will reduce the reallocating time from **O(m*n)** to **O(t*m)**. My first problem is that can I make this reallocating faster? 
Second, when computing an element on the "edge" of the matrix, the task has to make a communication with the nearby task, which may take considerable time in MPI. To reduce this, I guess I can split the origin matrix to several rectangles more foursquare not slender. But I don't how to do it, is there any keyword for the algorithm name for me to search?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate `m*n`, which will give you the number of cells. If you want to split this into `t` fields, every field needs to have `m*n/t` cells, or be a square with each side being `sqrt(m*n/t)` long.

I would think that the easiest way to do the load balancing would be creating a work queue, cutting the matrix into many more than just t pieces, and let each worker fetch a new piece of work once the first one is completed (or, if you have network delay, have a small local cache and keep it filled).

If you do this, it also won't matter that the method above may not make all squares exactly the same size due to rounding.

Answer (score 2):

Using only a big matrix is not the best way to handle a life game. Since the living cells tend to be sparse, adding a list of just the live cells lets you not waste time on all the empty areas.

You can assign sections of the work list to threads.